# Função em Python juntamente com html, como concilar?

Tags: html, python

Eu tenho um select:

```
<select class="form-control">
    <option value="0" selected>Selecione uma opção</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
</select>
```

E logo abaixo, mesclado, tenho o seguinte código em `Python`:

```
{% for objeto in objetos %}
    {% if objeto.escolha == 'opcao do select' %}
        FAÇA ISSO
    {% else %}
        FAÇA AQUILO
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Como faço para guardar o valor selecionado no `select` para poder ser usado no `if` do código `Python`?

Comment: Acredito que você queria pegar o valor do select e realizar uma alteração na página, porem o python renderiza a página e manda para a maquina do cliente, e só fazendo uma nova requisição que ele poderia pegar este valor e dai poderia fazer alguma ação, acredito que a melhor forma para solucionar o seu problema é fazendo a alteração utilizando javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A template engine não serve para fazer manipulações do DOM em tempo real. Para esse caso, utiliza-se JavaScript.

HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" id="select1" onchange="handleSelectChange()">
    <option value="0" selected>Selecione uma opção</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
</select>

<h1 id="text1"></h1>
```

JS:

```
var select = document.getElementById('select1');
var h1 = document.getElementById('text1');

function handleSelectChange(v)
{
    if(select.value == 1)
        h1.innerHTML = 'Selecionou a opção' + select.value.toString();
    else
        h1.innerHTML = 'Selecionou uma opção diferente de 1';

}
```

Hoje em dia, provavelmente, ninguém usa javascript puro como eu fiz acima, recomendo jQuery ou um framework js moderno como Vue.js e afins.

EDIT 1:

Lembrando que toda manipulação feita via JS fica no front-end, se quiser interagir com o back-end (Django eu imagino), pode-se utilizar Ajax.

Answer (score -2):

Se você estiver usando django, cria formulários para serem renderizados e no formulário coloca um javascript para quando mudar o valor selecionado. 
Estuda um pouco sobre formulários: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/